# market-api does not find apps above gingerbread depending on AID

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

I am using the standart market-api code - nothing special to post it here. I have three scenarios:

1. AID = 3.....  -> Apps are shown but only if their target is below 2.3
2. No AID -> same as 1
3. My AID (6...) -> HTTP 400

So It seems like is is only working with AIDs starting with '3'. However I need to resolve apps that are also above 2.3. Does some has a solution?  (I will give him definitely a bounty, because I can't find any infos.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setDeviceAndSDK method but it does not help at all. Also tried to compile the latest code with modificated values but still the same. So finally I use

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + pkg + "&hl=en"
```

to crawl all values I need.